# Javascript: anonymous function with jQuery as parameter

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I'm looking at a JavaScript plug-in for the first time, their instruction directs one to include referencing the jQuery API in the head of a HTML document.

The first line of JS in their plug-in entails what I've come to understand is a self-invoking anonymous function

```
(function($) {...} )(JQuery);
// ... represents many lines of script
```

1. Is an actual jQuery object being passed as an argument?
2. And to be clear, the $ is just an variable/object name receiving jQuery?

I've only been working with JS for about a year. Thanks!

Comment: `an actual jQuery object` - no, it's **the** jQuery object

Comment: Think about it like any other function in javascript. It's just a function that gets called immediately, with the `jQuery` object as a parameter. The function receives that parameter and names it `$`. Imagine the same pattern doing something completely different: `(function(a, b){ return a+b  })(2,2) == 4`

Comment: @JaromandaX It depends. It may be one of several jQuery objects loaded on the page. I've worked with widgets/mashups where we had to load our own private jQuery because the client had an incompatible (in one case, custom modified) version of jQuery loaded.

Comment: To the OP: if you are wondering why people suggest this construct it is because jQuery is not the only framework to use `$`.

Comment: @slebetman - ahh yes, multiple version of jQuery is a thing - forgot about that

Comment: 1. Which jQuery object are we referring to, the "classes" defined in the referenced library? Then 2. $ is just a name for the variable/object passed to it?

Comment: @stumpjumper64: Yes, the jQuery object exported by jQuery. Traditionally jQuery used the variable `$` for this object. But other libraries like prototype.js also use `$` for their own objects. Because of this jQuery changed to exporting `jQuery` instead and optionally can either also export `$` or not export `$` to prevent corrupting other people's code. People used to call this "ninja" mode. By using this construct you can always be sure that `$` refers to jQuery inside the function regardless of what other libraries are installed.

Comment: @slebetman et al. Ok, I think I've got this. A good learning experience. A self-invoking anonymous function at a high level (in my case) takes THE jQuery plugin/library that is referenced in a script tag as a parameter. Then, in the example that I'm seeing, that parameter is assigned a name, $, in that function. Lastly a method extend() is used inside the function to modify existing traits of the jQuery object. Phew.

Answer (score 0):

function a(){} -> this return a function object

(function a(){}) -> this is a function object

(function a(){})(...) -> call that function object to run with or without args

So it's just like a function call after all.